# Attempted to upgrade to 16.04 and can now only reach GRUB command line

Tags: command-line, grub2, 16.04, updates

I was downloading Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 then while depackaging everything froze. After a while I gave up waiting and forced shutdown.

When I restarted the computer all I had was the terminal in black open, nothing else.

I did `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`. It did not work but suggested to me a `dpkg` command that continued depackaging the update.

After a while the screen turned dark and there was no change. so I forced shutdown again.

Now I can only get to the grub command line. How do I enter from there the encrypted personal partition in order to resume the update? Or is there a way I can go back to 14.04? I also have a usb stick with Ubuntu 12 somewhere

[image]

Comment: the one that asks me to press tab and then gives me a string of writing....

Comment: thx yea it is grub2.02 ... I put a picture of the commands in the top post... what do I do from there?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is to repair your grub with the boot-repair-disk utility:

1. download boot-repair-disk .iso file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)
2. burn it on a DVD or USB stick
3. boot your PC from it
4. Select "Recommended repair" that solves the majority of bootsector/GRUB/MBR problems

more information on : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1831869

Comment: the official website gives me a 404 O.o is the program outdated?
"The sourceforge.net website is temporarily in static offline mode.
Only a very limited set of project pages are available until the main website returns to service."

Comment: This program is certainly not outdated. But it would seems there is a problem with sourceforge.net website. Try again later it is really useful to have it on a bootable usb stick. In the mean time you could try to boot with another ubuntu live usb and manually install boot-repair to it. see [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: looks like the sourceforge.net website is back online, if you want to try, you can access it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)

Comment: stupid question: how to see the boot repair usb on boot menu... I tried installing installing boot program via all 3 suggested methods but only 1 of them worked the liliboot... but now my usb does not appear on boot menu...

Comment: download the .iso file, install it to a usb stick, or if it's easier , burn it to a blank CD/DVD disk. reboot your pc/laptop with it (make sure your BIOS/UEFI allows it), and just start with the standard automated boot-repair-disk option.

Comment: :/ USB boot is on bios enabled... and LiLi USB creator was the only software with what I was able to install the boot repair ISO from the 3 suggested... I just reinstalled it a second time on my USB then try again and if it doesn't work sleep good night :) see you tomorow

Comment: nope sorry just tried :/ UEFI is on too... so it is not on legacy mode....

Comment: just tried with different USB slots :/

Comment: Bizarre, if you installed the iso properly on the stick it should boot from it when you reboot. have you check your bios/uefi setting for which order your computer does boot. if it s setup that it check the HDD before USB you need to change it, or to press one of the function key during bootup (this is different for each computer, typically F1 F2 F8 or F12).

Comment: Alternatively, if you still have your old ubuntu 12 stick as mentioned in your initial post, you could boot from it and install boot-repair as described in the 2nd option of this same [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: so basically same thing happened with supergrub and so I thought maybe its my USB sticks fault... so I tried to format the usb stick I usually keep my Ubuntu on but accidentally formatted my Ubuntu partition XD so no use in saving data since the data has been lost.... I put some basic Ubuntu system on incase I have windows problems but I think im going back on windows... thx for ur help

Comment: very sorry to hear you've lost your data, sorry I couldn't help you more

Comment: While this might answer the question, link only answers are not a good fit for this site. Please edit the answer to include the essential steps written in the link.

Comment: Answer edited, thank you @AndreaLazzarotto for your help and guidance.